# TableViewController does not show Top-/Bottombar

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitableview

I would like to jump from my initial `StartViewController`  to a `TableViewController` and back to the `initial View`. I tried to setup this in XCode Storyboard but there is one big problem:

The Top/Bottom Bar of the `TableViewController` is/are not visible. What's wrong here?

[image: Storyboard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have set your navigation bar hidden please check.
You can follow following steps:

1. Remove UINavigationController from First VC.
2. Just make a UIViewController with a toolbar at top and a UITableView below it.
3. Now the set UITableViewController's datasource and delegates to newly made ViewController.
4. Now if you present viewcontroller(made from step 2) modally from your firstview, you will see the toolbar along with UITableView.

Comment: No change. Checked and added self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO; to ViewDidLoad

Comment: But i don't want any Toolbars in the StartViewController.

Comment: Then you can try to present tableview modally rather than pushing it from firstview and add toolbar in it.

Comment: But how can I make the toolbar visible. In Storyboard they are visible, but in the Simulator I can only see the TableView (see the attached screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be presenting your table view modally. Try changing the segue type to 'push'.

Comment: @fabian Building on this answer, you don't need to create another segue from your `TableViewController` to your `StartViewController`, as this functionality is already implemented by the `back` button in the `Navigation Bar`, since you are using a `Navigation Controller`.

Comment: Type 'push' works great. But i want this nice 'modal flip' animation

Comment: Then you could embed the table view controller inside another navigation controller and present that modally.

Comment: Thanks Hendrik. It works. I just need to find out how to pop that 2nd NavigationController from the first one

Comment: Cool! Could you be so kind as to mark my answer as correct? Thanks.